# Derivation of the Schwarzschild solution

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, curvature, singularities

For the Derivation of the Schwarzschild solution my Professor use:

$R_{\mu\nu} = 0$ since we are in vacuum.

I see that we are in vacuum, but we assume a mass at point $r = 0$.
Thus, the curvature is nonzero.
But from $R_{\mu\nu} = 0$ we get $R = 0$ (Ricci scalar), that means the curvature is zero.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: "but we assume a mass at point r = 0. Thus, the curvature is nonzero" why?

Comment: Mass is curving spacetime not at a single point?

Comment: How do you know that? Spacetime does what Einstein's equations says it does (within this model). Einstein's equations tells us that if the energy density at a point vanishes, then $R_{\mu\nu} = 0$ at that point. The full curvature of the spacetime is described not just by a single number $R$ but by 20 numbers in the Riemann tensor $R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}$ which itself may not be zero.

Comment: So if R = 0, the curvature has not to be zero? What is R telling us?

Comment: $R$ tells us about the ``radius of curvature'' which is one aspect of the curvature, but not everything.

Comment: This helped a lot!

Comment: $R_{\mu\nu} = 0$ is true only *outside* of the central body.